# C++ RegOpenKeyEx - Error 6: The handle is invalid

Tags: c++

I am testing the following code and receiving the error: "RegOpenKeyEx failed with error 6: The handle is invalid", what am I doing wrong?
I am using WinXP, MS VS 2010, compiling in Unicode.

```
HKEY hKey;
if (!RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey)) {
    ErrorExit(TEXT("RegOpenKeyEx"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in your error handling.  As posted, this code can *never* generate a proper error message.  RegOpenKeyEx() is different from the majority of winapi functions, it returns the error code directly, you do *not* use GetLastError().

It needs to be rewritten to something like:

```
  HKEY hKey;
  LONG err = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
  if (err != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
      ErrorExit2(err, TEXT("RegOpenKeyEx"));
  }
```